# Updating MySQL database by a JFrame form while refreshing the J table on the JFrame form

Tags: java, mysql

[image]

I developed above form , to update MySQL database table 'employeeinfo'. Form also shows a J Table with current data in the database table 'employeeinfo'.

I coded to select J table row and get those in for to relevant text fields in the form.

But, I'm having trouble with updating the MySQL database by editing selected employees....**when I edit the text fields and hit update , database or the Jtable isn't updating **

Database do not updating and J table isn't refreshing..(may be because of database table isn't updating)

Update button ActionPerformed;

```
private void update_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

try{
    String val1 =txt_id.getText();
    String val2 =txt_name.getText();
    String val3 =txt_sname.getText();
    String val4 =((JTextField)bday_chooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String val5 =((JTextField)wday_chooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

    String sql = "update employeeinfo set EmployeeID='"+val1+"',Name='"+val2+"',Surname='"+val3+"', BirthDate='"+val4+"',WorkStartedDate='"+val5+"' where EmployeeID='"+val1+"' ";

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.execute();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Data Updated...");

}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
updateTable();}
```

updateTable Method;

```
private void updateTable(){

try {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM employeeinfo";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    table_empinfo.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error : "+ex);
}}
```

Comment: it looks a little bit weired that you update the EmployeeID with val1 and in the same process you use this value to identify the entry that has to be updated... you know what I mean? you have to use the old EmployeeID to update the correct row in your database.

Comment: @Stefan Beike  It was the mistake :) now it's working ...thanks for the comment :)